# Drupal node title as URL permalinks

Tags: theming, nodes, 6

How can I use Drupal node title as URL Permalink just like wordpress %postname% ?

or even change the "node" from example.com/node/id ? (Drupal 6)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Enable module Path. it is provided in Drupal core.
If you want automatically generate url aliases for new nodes - install [Pathauto](http://drupal.org/project/pathauto)

> The Pathauto module automatically generates URL/path aliases for various kinds of content (nodes, taxonomy terms, users) without requiring the user to manually specify the path alias. This allows you to have URL aliases like /category/my-node-title instead of /node/123. The aliases are based upon a "pattern" system that uses tokens which the administrator can change.